# What the difference between method `stop` and `pause` in AVAudio menber

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm a fresh man in AVFoundation. I write a demo about AVAudio and played a music. when i call **stop:** method at 5th sec, it stoped. The i called **play**, it start at 6th sec. It is same replace of **stop:** with **pause**. In my opion, **stop:** method will reset currentTime, but **pause:** do not. But in my code, there has no difference.

Then I read the document. It says:

`- (void)pause;          /* pauses playback, but remains ready to play. */
- (void)stop;           /* stops playback. no longer ready to play. */`

I'm confused about it. What the difference between `stop:` and `pause:`. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> - (void)stop

Calling `stop` method, or allowing a sound to finish playing, undoes the setup performed upon calling the play or prepareToPlay methods.

The stop method does not reset the value of the currentTime property to 0. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call play, playback resumes at the point where it left off.

> - (void)pause

Calling `pause` leaves the audio player prepared to play; it does not release the audio hardware that was acquired upon calling play or prepareToPlay.

Comment: Regarding resuming from the current time when pressing play again, this was perhaps true at one point in the past, but it's not true now. From the docs:

"The AudioSource.stop function stops the currently set Audio clip from playing. The Audio clip plays from the beginning the next time you play it."

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Stop.html